# Efficiently creating map using imshow and (real-life) coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, imshow

I currently have a problem which I can't think of an efficient (O(n)) solution to, for which I believe there is one.

Given a list of real coordinates (not matrix index coordinates) e.g. (342873, 847219), as well as a unique list of possible X and Y coordinates, I want to be able to create a map by using numpy's imshow, where points that don't exist remain blank, and those that are, are coloured (just the same colour/containing the same value, for now).

For example, given

```
x_bins # unique list of x-coords possible
y_bins # unique list of y-coords possible
locations # list of (x, y) pairs
```

What I have currently done is to (failing to come up with what I imagine is the optimal approach) build the list of all coordinates using meshgrid, NaN-ing out the whole thing, then using going over the list of locations along with a map of each x/y-coord to its index respectively to set that element of the matrix to 1 accordingly.

Any hints as to how to approach this more elegantly (and getting the map to scale properly with these coordinates, as the matrix currently ignores scale when there are larger or smaller gaps between coordinates) would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why not simply using a scatter plot?

Comment: I probably could have included more context. The image I'm trying to generate represents spatial data, so I want the plotted result to represent a continuous image, which will ultimately show different shaded areas based on how an area is labelled. I have used a scatter plot to see at least *what* the image should look like with plots in areas with coordinates so I know when I've gotten imshow working.

Comment: How do the bins relate to the image you want to display? Is there a mapping between image pixels and bins?